# RavenDB Index Querying on Nested Properties

Tags: indexing, mapreduce, ravendb

sssI currently have an index called SchoolMetrics that aggregates several fields on the School field as the key and produces documents like this:

```
{ 
    School: {
      SchoolId: 1234
      Name: "asdf"
    }
    StudentCount: 1234,
    CourseCount: 1234
 }
```

My index map is defined as:

```
from s in docs.Metrics
where s.School != null
select new
{
    s.School,
    s.StudentCount,
    s.CourseCount
}
```

And the reduce is:

```
from s in results
group s by s.School
into g
select new
{
    School= g.Key,
    StudentCount = g.Sum(x => x.StudentCount),
    CourseCount = g.Sum(x => x.CourseCount)
}
```

When I try to do a query such a:
http://localhost:8080/databases/Database/indexes/SchoolMetrics?query=School.SchoolId:1234

It gives me this error:

```
 "System.ArgumentException: The field 'School.SchoolId' is not indexed, cannot query on fields that are not indexed
   at Raven.Database.Indexing.Index.IndexQueryOperation.AssertQueryDoesNotContainFieldsThatAreNotIndexes() in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Database\Indexing\Index.cs:line 639
   at Raven.Database.Indexing.Index.IndexQueryOperation.<Query>d__24.MoveNext() in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Database\Indexing\Index.cs:line 558
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass70.<Query>b__68(IStorageActionsAccessor actions) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 705
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.ExecuteBatch(Action`1 action) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Storage.Esent\TransactionalStorage.cs:line 378
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Batch(Action`1 action) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Storage.Esent\TransactionalStorage.cs:line 341
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.Query(String index, IndexQuery query) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 652
   at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.Index.PerformQueryAgainstExistingIndex(IHttpContext context, String index, IndexQuery indexQuery, Guid& indexEtag) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\Index.cs:line 150
   at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.Index.ExecuteQuery(IHttpContext context, String index, Guid& indexEtag) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\Index.cs:line 136
   at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.Index.GetIndexQueryRessult(IHttpContext context, String index) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\Index.cs:line 92
   at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.Index.OnGet(IHttpContext context, String index) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\Index.cs:line 84
   at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.Index.Respond(IHttpContext context) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\Index.cs:line 46
   at Raven.Http.HttpServer.DispatchRequest(IHttpContext ctx) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Http\HttpServer.cs:line 399
   at Raven.Http.HttpServer.HandleActualRequest(IHttpContext ctx) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Http\HttpServer.cs:line 222"
```

What's weirder is that when I try querying on the StudentCount or CourseCount fields it works... I've tried adding an analyzer on the School.SchoolId field but that doesn't seem to help... I've also tried flattening out the resulting document and I get the same error. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Thomas' note, you have to understand that we are looking at the final output from the index as the indexed item.
And if you are indexing a complex object, it is going to be indexed as a Json value, not as something that you can query on further.

Comment: So, is there any option in RavenDB, to simultaneously filter several properties of complex object which is stored in nested collection, without fanout indexes? I describe my case [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42030294/ravendb-indexing-and-querying-complex-hierarhical-data-nested-properties), please assist, if you can.

Answer (score 2):

You are grouping by the School object. How about flattening the index?

```cs
from s in docs.Metrics
where s.School != null
select new
{
    SchoolId = s.School.SchoolId,
    s.StudentCount,
    s.CourseCount
}

from s in results
group s by s.SchoolId
into g
select new
{
    SchoolId = g.Key,
    StudentCount = g.Sum(x => x.StudentCount),
    CourseCount = g.Sum(x => x.CourseCount)
}
```