# RavenDB - Indexing and querying complex hierarhical data (nested properties)

Tags: c#, linq, indexing, ravendb, querying

I have a docuemnt like this:

```
public class Order
{
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItem> Items { get; set; }  
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

And I need to query collection of theese documents like this:

```
var q = session.Query<Order_Index.Result, Order_Index>()
    .Where(o => o.ClientName.StartsWith("Jho") &&
                o.Items.Any(i => i.ProductCode == "Book" && i.Quantity >= 10))
    .OfType<Order>();
```

Every example of indexing and querying hierarhical data, that I found, shows only case, when only one property of complex nested object is used in separate query expression. e.g.:

```
var q = session.Query<Order_Index.Result, Order_Index>()
    .Where(o => o.ClientName.StartsWith("Jho") &&
                o.ItemProductCodes.Any(c => c == "Book") &&
                o.ItemQuantities.Any(qty => qty >= 10))
```

but none of them consider my situation.

I tried to index ProductCode and Quantity as separate collections and then join them by collection index while querying, but this throws some kind of Linq translation exception. I wonder, is there any opportunity to do this kind of querying in RavenDB?

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Order> session = new List<Order>() {
                new Order() { ClientName = "Jho", Items = new List<OrderItem>() { 
                        new OrderItem() { ProductCode = "abc", Quantity = 1},
                        new OrderItem() { ProductCode = "def", Quantity = 4},
                        new OrderItem() { ProductCode = "Book", Quantity = 5},
                        new OrderItem() { ProductCode = "jkl", Quantity = 10}
                   }
                },
                new Order() { ClientName = "Mary", Items = new List<OrderItem>() { 
                        new OrderItem() { ProductCode = "mno", Quantity = 2},
                        new OrderItem() { ProductCode = "pqr", Quantity = 3},
                        new OrderItem() { ProductCode = "stu", Quantity = 4},
                        new OrderItem() { ProductCode = "vwx", Quantity = 5}
                    }
                },
                new Order() { ClientName = "Jho", Items = new List<OrderItem>() { 
                        new OrderItem() { ProductCode = "abc", Quantity = 28},
                        new OrderItem() { ProductCode = "cdf", Quantity = 7},
                        new OrderItem() { ProductCode = "Book", Quantity = 26},
                        new OrderItem() { ProductCode = "jkl", Quantity = 5}
                    }
                }
            };

            var q = session.Where(o => o.ClientName.StartsWith("Jho") && o.Items.Where(i => i.ProductCode == "Book" && i.Quantity >= 10).Any()).ToList();
        }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
        public List<OrderItem> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class OrderItem
    {
        public string ProductCode { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: It throws the same exception as my Join attempt that i mentioned:

_System.InvalidOperationException' in Raven.Client.Lightweight.dll Additional information: Cannot understand how to translate <expression here>_

I tried this query:

`query.Where(x => x.Services.Select(s => (s.Name.StartsWith(queryString) || s.Description.StartsWith(queryString)) && s.MinCost >= minCost).Any())`

Comment: I added test data and changed a Select to a where.  I get no errors so I suspect some of the object may be null;

Comment: It still throws the same exception. My documents are stored in RavenDB, not in in-memory list. I believe that Liq to Object can execute such query, but I have a problem with RavenDB

Comment: See Raven webpage : https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/client-api/session/querying/how-to-query

Comment: I have read RavenDB docs, unfortunately, there is no answer to my question

Comment: You classes have to match the database.  If they do then this should work : var q = session.Query<Employee>().Where(o => o.ClientName.StartsWith("Jho") && o.Items.Where(i => i.ProductCode == "Book" && i.Quantity >= 10).Any()).ToList();

Comment: What do you mean by the words "You classes have to match the database"? They matches index result, I need custom index to make text properties analyzed. Index result should match document exactly? May be I need to store all properties in index? I will try your solution with auto index.

Comment: The datatype and property names (lower/upper case) must match between database and c# code.